# Is it possible to click on multiple links from a single command in ruby watir

Tags: ruby, watir

I have a cucumber statement which looks like this,`Then i navigate to "page_name": "page1> page2> page3"`

where `page_name` is a dummy variable to put the name of the page to which I am navigating to. The other argument is the path which has to be followed to reach the required page. I cannot hard code the path as it is of lenght 4 sometimes. I am using a `.yml` file to give the hrefs for the respective names.

```
Ex: page1= link1,
page2= link2,
page3= link3
```

**Is it possible to write a single ruby function to do this?**

Comment: Can you click multiple links with a single click (even maually)?

Comment: i know, but what i want to know is if its possible to write a function in ruby which can click on the links while looping through the links.

Comment: Lopping through the links and clicking one after the other would be possible, however you would most likely have to create a new browser instance for each link, since when you click link 1, you're on another page which may not contain link 2 from your previous page.

Comment: Our console is designed in a way where i can see all the links at all times even though i am on different pages.I just wan to know how the looping should be handled.

Comment: This is a test smell. Do you *really* want Watir to navigate by page name? People don't do that, and Cucumber tests should emulate what people do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would be possible. You could:

1. Get the path "page1> page2> page3" from the Cucumber step
2. Split the path on the "> "
3. Iterate through the path to:

   1. Get the href from the yml file
   2. Click on that link

For example, this might look like:

```
Then /i navigate to ".*": ".*"/ do |page_name, path|
  path.split('> ').each do |page|
    # Determine which link to click (assuming that the yml file gives you respective hrefs)
    href = get_link_from_yml(page)  # (You will need to create this method)

    # Click the link
    @browser.link(:href => href).click
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried using the above method and i am getting an error saying " expected one of [String, Regexp], got nil:NilClass (TypeError)".

Comment: That likely means your `href` value is nil. Check that whatever you implmented for `get_link_from_yml` is actually returning what you expect for each page.

Comment: i haven't written an explicit method to get the links, instead i have assigned the .yml file to a variable and then i am calling it when needed. Its shown here:                                           config = YAML.load_file("test.yml")                              href= config[page] , this returns me only the href of page1.

Comment: Did you try debugging to make sure that the `page` is correct and that your yaml responds propertly to that value? The fact that you say it only returns the href of page1 means either your yaml is incorrect or `page` is not as expected.

Comment: I think i found the problem. My href starts with # so the rest of the string is commented.How do i solve this.

Comment: It can depend on the yaml parser, but I think the common approach is to put double quotes around the value - ex "#the-href"